# Popup the image icon which resides in my UIView-Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I do have a view with an image icon, I want to popup that image when I clicked on that icon.
I think it is possible with `UIpopovercontroller`.
I am a new guy to iPhone development. hope your help. Thanx..

Comment: There is no popover in iphone.. For iPad you can use that.

Comment: you mean when you tap on image icon then its show bigger right?

Comment: @NitinGohel: u r right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this like this, create outlet of your icon in .h file and make it user interaction property selected

```
{
    UIImageView *imgView;
    UIImageView *closeimgView;
}
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *iconIv;
```

and in .m file.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UITapGestureRecognizer* ivGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ivTapped:)];

    [imageIv addGestureRecognizer:ivGesture];
}
- (void)ivTapped:(id)sender
{
    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 50, 250, 350)]; //create appropriate frame
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhone.jpg"];
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

    [self.view addSubview:imgView];

    closeimgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(275, 45, 25, 25)]; //create appropriate frame
    closeimgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"close_btn.png"];
    closeimgView.userInteractionEnabled =YES;
    closeimgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    [self.view addSubview:closeimgView];

    UITapGestureRecognizer* closeivGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(closeivTapped:)];

    [closeimgView addGestureRecognizer:closeivGesture];


}

- (void)closeivTapped:(id)sender
{
    [imgView removeFromSuperview];
     [closeimgView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: thanx it is working.. i need some more really good looking with a close button and a background overlay. if u found anything there help me..

Comment: and for background overlay create a view that contain this imageviews.